# APDU command for reading a Dedicated File

Tags: apdu

My goal is reading the content of a DF (Dedicated File). 
After selecting a DF like PKCS#15 AID (A0 00 00 00 63 50 4B 43 53 2D 31 35), which APDU command can i use to know his EFs (Elementary File)?

Answer (score 2):

There is no APDU command to get list of EFs under a DF.

Normally, you get a specification of the card containing tree structure of the files inside.

If you don't have the specification, you can still get the files using brute-force by creating simple application that sends SELECT commands for file ID '0000' to 'FFFF' with P1 = '02' (Select EF under current DF). From my experience, the loop took few hours to complete.

Comment: Didn't this brute force make the card locked?

Comment: I've never experienced card locked because of select command. Normally, card is locked because of incorrect authentication or incorrect verification

Answer (score 2):

Usually you do not need such listing once the PKCS#15 has been selected.
You must read the [PKCS#15 specification](ftp://ftp.rsasecurity.com/pub/pkcs/pkcs-15/pkcs-15v1_1.pdf) from RSA Labs which tells you to read ODF file (which is some sort of "table of contents"), then read the DODF, etc...

Answer (score 0):

When you write for the first time in your card, you create your DF and EF in order to insert informations. Your EF has a name that can help you to read informations. 
If you want to read the content of the EF file you must know the name of your file and the documentation of the card can help you to get information.

What's the name of the card that you try to read?